# How can I format date -u so that the results include timezone offset in a Mac OSX terminal session?

Tags: macos, date, time, textmate, utc

In a terminal session I can use date -u to get
 
Mon Mar 16 03:34:39 2009 UTC
However, I'd like to include the offset.  I'm modifying a TextMate tab trigger so that I can insert the full date including the local offset, in standard UTC format.  I believe that would be in the following form:
Mon Mar 16 03:34:39 2009 UTC -0500

So, as you can see, I don't know how to get the timezone offset and combine that with formatted date results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo `date -u` `date +%z`
```

Comment: Replaced date -u +%z by date +%z. the first one would always return +0000.